# Bitcoin UTXO anatomy

Tags: utxo, pycoin

I've been using a command line tool to fetch spendables from a Bitcoin address. Given an address the following command ([source](https://github.com/richardkiss/pycoin/blob/master/COMMAND-LINE-TOOLS.md)) ouptuts UTXOs the address can spend.

tx -i 1A3cbxFC4zrfgxEb6GhAe97m2rSEyvUetp
 >
4db2ddb59e0cd123d8d0715da9dddbe6b2697c5a1d83163cc049dcc152d1f7ed/0/76a9146337aefd82e6c1f83ab505b78c3bcc413b49364088ac/1061/0/0/0

The format is address/utxo index/script hash/...
However I do not know what the last 4 elements mean, I'm guessing amount, but don't know what the 3 zeros that come afterwards mean - any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As per [the source](https://github.com/richardkiss/pycoin/blob/11f60a7cb7e74e2280ee50f5a3e958becf45500c/pycoin/coins/bitcoin/Spendable.py#L68), the parts of that output are:

```
tx_hash/tx_out_index/script/coin_value/block_index_available/does_seem_spent/block_index_spent
```